# postgresql logical replication replica identity on whole user tables

Tags: postgresql, replication

Customer has about 4960 tables in different schemas and will apply a logical replication whole database.
Is there any easy way to set 4960 tables' **replica identity full**. (alter <schema.table> replica identity full)
.

Customer is regularly upgrading/updating commercial licensed (not opensource) product and each update/upgrade reset table specifications so need to apply replica identity settings again after upgrade/update :)

So I am looking for better solution instead of applying 4960 alter statements

Thanks

Comment: Generate the alterations in a loop? What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: Why "full"? The primary key is better.

Comment: Hello @LaurenzAlbe
Could not change anything on table design. Vendor and customer do not let me and as I wrote in my question. Table properties resets by installer while update or upgrade

Comment: Hello @RichardHuxton
Waht about following code ? I am not good at plpgsql 
DO $$
DECLARE
    schema_name TEXT;
    table_name TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR schema_name, table_name IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema IN ('schema1',!schema2',.....)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;', schema_name, table_name);
    END LOOP;
END $$;

Comment: I can't really read the code properly in a comment, but yes, that seems to be the general idea.

Comment: A commercially available software that doesn't create primary keys on the tables? Somebody actually dares to take money for that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I got it what do you mean but what can I say that the vendor's workload management şs that way

Comment: I am not blaming you, and the code in your comment looks good.